# Unable to read new records from a table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a data adapter with 4 tables in a dataset. When I update a new record to the table it appears in the SQL database and the associated datagridivew has been reloaded with the dat in the table, but when I try and read the new record using the following code it can't find the record.

```vb
Dim row As DataRow = dsSrvAV.Tables("ServiceAvailability").Select("ID = " & intRecordID).FirstOrDefault()
```

The same code is used to read other records that were in the database when the application opened, it's just new records that it can't read.

This is the code that writes the new records

```vb
Dim newAvailability As DataRow = dsSrvAV.Tables("ServiceAvailability").NewRow()

'Add some data to it
newAvailability("Service_ID") = cboServices.SelectedValue
newAvailability("Date") = Format(dtpDate.Value.ToString, "Short Date")
newAvailability("Downtime") = nudDowntime.Value
newAvailability("Notes") = txtNotes.Text
newAvailability("MajorIncident") = txtMajorIncident.Text
newAvailability("ActionsTaken") = txtActionsTaken.Text
newAvailability("Type") = cboType.SelectedValue
newAvailability("Root_Cause") = txtRootCause.Text

'Add it to the table
dsSrvAV.Tables("ServiceAvailability").Rows.Add(newAvailability)

'Update the adapter
daSrvAv.Update(dsSrvAV, "ServiceAvailability")
dsSrvAV.Tables("ServiceAvailability").AcceptChanges()
```

Can anyone offer any thoughts as to why this won't allow new records to be read back.

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Where are you getting intRecordId from? Are you sure its the correct value? Is the ID column an int?

Comment: The intRecord is picked up from the datagridview which gets it from the pkey value in the database. It works ok for all other records that exist in the database, it's just newly add ones that it can't find.

Comment: And `dsSrvAV` is definitely pointing to the same `DataSet` object in both places?

Comment: Is intRecordID an autonumber record in the DB?

Comment: dsSrvAV is pointing to the same dataset throughout the application and the intRecordID has been generated from an autonumber in the DB

Comment: Okay (and assuming that intRecordID really is correct) it might be a caching thing. Could you try and close your dsSrvAv dataset, and then re-open it, and then do the select?

Comment: Wait.... your code after 'Update the adapter comment.... you have 'daSrvAv' is that correct? (i know its an adapter)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I took that code from an example somewhere on MSDN.

Comment: When responding to someone, you must put an at-sign in front of their name so that they get a notification.  Otherwise, they won't know that you responded to them unless they just happen to come back to your question and refresh the page.  For instance, to respond to robinick, you need to put @robnick somewhere in the comment.

Comment: Sorry about that @Steven-Doggart, I'm just new here and still learning.

Comment: I've cleared the dataset and reopened it and it's now working - does this not put extra load on the database unnecessarily? @robnick

Comment: What if you call `Select`, like that, right after the line where you call `AcceptChanges`.  Does it work there?

Comment: I've added a 'Select' after the 'AcceptChanges' but this brings the original problem back. @StevenDoggart

Answer (score 0):

Per comments - this solved the issue.

Close your dsSrvAv dataset, and then re-open it, and then do the select.

Regardng performance: are you adding 1 record per second of 1,000,000. If its 1,000,000 then yes there's an overhead. If its 1 per second there isn't any noticable overhead.